# Prove existence of retraction

Tags: general-topology, algebraic-topology

I was reading the Example 1.24 of *Algebraic topology - A. Hatcher* where he compute the fundamental group of $\pi_1(\mathbb R^3-K_{mn})$, with $K_{mn}$ torus knot.

In p.48 whe can find the following:

> To compute $\pi_1 (X)$ we apply van Kampen’s theorem to the decomposition of $X$
> as the union of $X_m$ and $X_n$ , or more properly, open neighborhoods of these two
> sets that deformation retract onto them-

I cannot prove why we can always find open neighborhoods $U$ and $V$ of $X_n$ and $X_m$ that deformation retract onto them.

Moreover, why $U\cap V$ deformation retracts onto $X_m\cap X_n$?

Comment: Can you do this for the cylinder without the identifications? That's all there is to it, because the boundary of $X_m$ and $X_n$ as subsets of $X_{mn}$ is separated from the subset of the cylinder on which we have done identifications.

Comment: What are $X_n, X_m$?